# Which Lent should someone Baptized in an Eastern Roman Catholic rite follow?

Tags: catholicism, lent, eastern-catholicism, liturgical-rite

## Issue

Lent is treated slightly differently across the Catholic Rites.

In the Melkite Rite, the Great Lent begins [on the Vespers of Clean Monday](http://www.mliles.com/melkite/greatlentcleanmondayvespers.shtml), which is the Monday after Ash Wednesday ([Feb 19th this year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_Monday)), and ends on [the Friday after the 5th Sunday of Lent](http://www.mliles.com/melkite/greatlentsundaysfifth.shtml).  This is precisely 40 days, counts Sundays and has stricter a [stricter abstinence obligation](https://www.stjohnmelkite.com/fasting/) than the Latin Rite form of Lent. Namely, that abstinence be practiced on all days of Lent except for Palm Sunday and the Feast of the Annunciation.

In the Roman Catholic Rite, [lent](http://antiochian.org/node/25432) begins on Ash Wednesday and ends on Holy Thursday.  This includes Sundays [only as far as our conscience dictates](http://www.usccb.org/prayer-and-worship/liturgical-year/lent/questions-and-answers-about-lent.cfm).

## Question

If someone is baptized, given first communion, and confirmed as a Melkite Catholic, but has otherwise grown up in the Western Rite, does Melkite doctrine state that there can be a choice in which Lent a believer chooses to follow?

Comment: I think you may be mistaken in identifying the Friday after the fifth Sunday in Great Lent as being Good Friday.  It is the week before Good Friday, and is followed by Lazarus Saturday and Palm Sunday, which are not, in Eastern tradition,  part of Lent.

Comment: @davidlol edited accordingly

Comment: Which church do you consider yourself a member of? That should pretty much give you an answer.

Comment: I consider myself a member of the Western Rite.

Comment: Why do you doubt that observing the Western Rite Lent is the right thing for you? Whose approval do you want?

Comment: So there is no specific doctrine on the matter then?

Comment: Doctrine from whom? The doctrine of the Western Rite, the church that you are a member of, is that you should observe the Western Rite .  The Eastern Rite may or may not permit you to observe the Western Rite, but you aren't a member of them.

Comment: But is he a member of the Western Rite,  merely because he considers himself to be one? Canon 112 section two says the practice, however prolonged,  of receiving the sacraments in a particular Rite does not entail enrollment in that rite. Of course, on one level, he can do anything he pleases, but if the question is premised on Church law, then canon 112 seems to say that he is not a member of the Western rite, whatever he considers himself.

Comment: So, if I'm getting this right, based on Canon Law I am a member of an Eastern Rite, but in this case it doesn't hold too much gravity over what lent I choose to practice. Correct?

Comment: Yes, you are Eastern rite,. But whether Eastern Rite members are permitted to observe western rite lent, has not been answered yet. I don't know the answer, but was merely clarifying the question. Hopefully someone will answer it.

Comment: @davidlol Recent edits I made reflect this clarification.

Comment: I think this question would be improved by identifying when "Clean Monday" is (I *think* it's the Monday before Ash Wednesday). It may also be of note that part of the Latin Church actually "goes purple" and omits all Alleluias and the Gloria at Mass **three Sundays before Ash Wednesday** — that's what is prescribed for the Ordinariate Use.

Comment: @davidlol But does enrolment in a Church have any relevance to observing lent?

Comment: @curiousdannii Well that seems to be the question. I don't know the answer, though.  It might in that as a general rule people are required to follow the rules of the church they belong to, but there may be exceptions. I don't know, but it seems not as simple as DJClayworth suggested, that's what I meant.

Comment: @davidlol Is "belong to" different from "attend regularly?" If participating regularly in the sacraments has no bearing on your enrolment, then I'd say you belong to the one you attend, which may not be the one you are enrolled in.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I have edited the question to include when Clean Monday occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Code of Canons of the Eastern Churches codifies common portions of the canon law of all the Eastern Catholic Churches within the (Roman) Catholic Church.

Canon 883 says

> The Christian faithful who are outside the territorial boundaries of their own Church sui juris can adopt fully for themselves the feast days and days of penance which are in force where they are staying.

This shows that someone whose own Church is an Eastern Rite Church,  but who lives in a Western country, is free to observe Lent according to the Latin rite instead of the rite of his own Church.

The question is about someone attending a Latin rite Church, rather than living in  Latin rite territory,  but in practice most Eastern Rite Catholics regularly attending a Latin Rite parish will do so because of where they live, and so I offer this answer.

In years when Easter is the same East and West, Clean Monday  is 2 days prior to Western Ash Wednesday and Eastern Lent ends 2 days before Palm Sunday. This year Eastern Easter is one eeek later. There are obvious disadvantages in fasting according to one calendar but  using the liturgy of another as one could be fasting in preparation for Easter even while celebrating it in church.

[Source](http://www.intratext.com/IXT/ENG1199/_POJ.HTM)

Comment: Is territory understood as territory within a political body or diocese/eparchy?

Comment: Territory is the area in which a Church (or its Orthodox equivalent) was historically dominnant.In the case of the Bulgarian, Ethiopian or Romanian churches their teritory is Bulgaria, Ethiopia or Romania respectively. The Melkite covers several middle Eastern countries. The whole  of the Americas is Latin territory, as is Western Europe and Australia.  There are eparchies etc of Eastern Churches in Western countries, e, g.  the Newton eparchy of the Melkite Church, but is outside the territory of the Melkite patriarchy.